# OpenMP results not as expected

Tags: c++, openmp

I have class that contains dynamic 3d array. Object of the class calls a function that does some calculation to populate 1d array and in the end populate  object's 3d array with the 1d array data.The size of 1d array is same as of 3d array.
I am using Openmp to fasten the calculation. Single thread execution is giving correct result but as soon I go to multiple threads I get weird result. 
Sample Code is given below. Kindly, help to resolve the issue.

```
class A (
     void func(float *buf);
     void populateRes(*t); 
      private:
         float ***res;
      };

 A a[n];
 int nthrd = omp_get_num_threads();
 float *buf;
 while (cnt < nz)
 {
      #pragma omp parallel shared(cnt) private(buf, tid, omp_i)
      {
           if(cnt == 0 )
             buf = new float[x*y*z];

           #pragma omp for
           for(omp_i=0; omp_i<n; omp_i++)
           { 
              a[omp_i].func(buf);
              a[omp_i].populateRes(buf);
            }
       }
       cnt++;
       if(cnt >= nz)
          delete []buf;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP does not preserve the values of `private` variables between different entries into the same `parallel` region, the same way that values of automatic local variables are not preserved between different invocations of a function (unless they are declared `static`). In fact, in most OpenMP implementations, `parallel` regions are separate functions and `private` variables are automatic.

This makes your code erroneous since `buf` would only be allocated on the first iteration of the loop, but then in the next iterations your code would operate on a new *uninitialised* local copy. It might happen (by pure chance) that the content of the stack of a particular thread is not changed and thus `buf` retains its value. Also deleting `buf` outside of the `parallel` region ignores the fact that there were multiple calls to `new`.

If you'd like to allocate `buf` only once, you should put the `while` loop inside the `parallel` region and not vice versa. This would also improve the performance since the `parallel` region would be entered only once and there is an overhead associated with each entry.

```
A a[n];

#pragma omp parallel
{
   float *buf = new float[x*y*z];
   for (int cnt = 0; cnt < nz; cnt++)
   {
      #pragma omp for
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         a[i].func(buf);
         a[i].populateRes(buf);
      }
   }
   delete [] buf;
}
```

(I don't see `tid` being used inside so I've taken the liberty to remove it from the list of `private` variables)

Changing the nesting of both loops is possible since there is an implicit barrier at the end of the `for` worksharing constuct. I don't know if there is other code that you've omitted but given the code from the question, the `cnt` loop could be even nested inside the worksharing construct, i.e.:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   float *buf = new float[x*y*z];
   #pragma omp for
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for (int cnt = 0; cnt < nz; cnt++)
      {
         a[i].func(buf);
         a[i].populateRes(buf);
      }
   }
   delete [] buf;
}
```